# How to convert "Day_Name Month Day_No. Time Year" to date format?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a **date** column in a **df** with values like `Fri Apr 01 16:41:32 +0000 2022`. I want to convert it into proper date column format `01/04/2022 16:41:32`. Where 01 is day and 04 is the month.

Any guidance please?

Comment: Since it is already separed in spaces, just split(), then use a diccionary that you manually created for the month, and the rest is just discarding and reordering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) for getting `datetime` then with [`Series.dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) convert to desired format.

```
import pandas as pd

# example df
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['Fri Apr 01 16:41:32 +0000 2022' , 
                            'Sat Apr 02 16:41:32 +0000 2022']})


df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
print(df)
```

---

```
                  date
0  01/04/2022 16:41:32
1  02/04/2022 16:41:32
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to get the datetime type.

```
from dateutil import parser
date=parser.parse("Fri Apr 01 16:41:32 +0000 2022")
```

If you want a specific string format, you can then use `strftime()`

Answer (score 0):

first create a dictionary from month and the number of month for example for key "apr" value is 04.

Then with regex create a function for extract the name of month, year, time and day and then with the apply method, apply it on all rows and store output in a new column as a tuple.

now you can use from apply method again for create custom column as

```
datetime.datetime(year= ..., Month=..., ...)
```